# log4j stop creating daily log file

Tags: tomcat, log4j

Hi i'm using Tomcat and Log4j to run and log my webapp.

I set my log4j properties.

```
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c %M:%L %m%n

log4j.appender.dailyfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dailyfile.File=logs/debuglog/debug.log
log4j.appender.dailyfile.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.dailyfile.Append=true
log4j.appender.dailyfile.DatePattern='.'yyyyMMdd
log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %C{1}.%M %m [%t]%n
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=20
```

With the properties above, I copied my program(I call it AAA here) war file into tomcat/webapps, ran Tomcat server. As you know after running Tomcat, Tomcat create a new folder AAA and put all the data extracted from war file in it. Everything worked fine. tomcat created daily log files in the path written in property option. However a problem occured when I copy all the data in AAA folder into webapps/ROOT. tomcat stopped creating daily log files, it just overwrites in existing one.